# Book about a girl and her male friend who die while bungee jumping; she goes to Hell and becomes a demon, while he goes to Heaven and becomes an angel

Tags: story-identification, books

I need to find a book I read around 2017-2019. The cover showed a girl and was mainly red.

This book is about a girl who is "normal" as she describes it. She has brown hair, brown eyes, and is relatively short. Then there's her best friend/boyfriend. He has blond hair, blue eyes, and is very tall.

They both die while bungee jumping, but she gets sent to Hell while he is sent to Heaven. After spending some time in Hell, she is one of the "demons" who gets sent to Earth to distribute karma to people on Earth. While doing so, she meets her best friend, who is a guardian angel or something.

Please help me find this book!!!